# Extracting BIOS from Motherboard

Tags: bios

I want to extract the BIOS software from EEPROM chip on Motherboard. Some kind of ISO image of the chip. Is it even possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: At least in the old days it was possible, unless it was a high security MB. But the method depended on the MB. Since you can usually download upgrades for the BIOS, you might find the content on internet. If splash screen is off, you can see the BIOS id at boot time.

Comment: Find a PC memory map of the first megabyte.  The BIOS code is at a fixed memory region, and should be readable when in real mode (e.g. DOS mode rather than in protected mode that Win7 or Linux uses).  BTW ISO specifies a filesystem format for optical discs.  Memory images are most likely plain binary images (i.e. the raw contents of memory).

Comment: *"I want to extract the BIOS software from EEPROM chip"* -- It's not likely to be an EEPROM.  EEPROMS are typically not programmable locally on the board.  It's most likely a Flash chip.  Don't bother arguing that flash is actually a type of EEPROM.  Nowadays the manufacturers and vendors  treat them as two distinct storage memory types.  EEPROMs typically now have serial interfaces (e.g. I2C) rather than parallel.

Comment: @sawdust - Since when was EEPROMS not programmable?

Comment: I know I can download. But I am asking a specific method.

Comment: Can anybody explain the downvote ??

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is memory map ?

Comment: @Ramhound -- I specifically wrote *"typically not programmable **locally on the board**"*.  I should have also specified "parallel".  The parallel (i.e. not serial) EEPROMs that I have used (in the past) all required voltages and circuitry typically not on a board.  These EEPROMS had to be programmed (i.e. erased and written) on a device called a programmer.  The typical EEPROM found today on a board is almost always serial, e.g. I2C or 1-Wire, and can be written and read by the host processor.

Comment: *"Could you please explain what exactly is memory map ?'* --  It's a list of (physical) memory addresses, and what is at those locations.  See   https://www.google.com/search?q=pc+memory+map&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CB4QsARqFQoTCNGHvejBkMYCFY8WkgodtFkAkw&biw=1106&bih=788  FWIW I did what you're asking on a 80386 laptop back in the day.

Comment: @MikkelAlanStokkebyeC - How does the user do this?  The author very clearly ask for instructions on HOW to do this if it was possible.  You seem to be just submitting a comment saying it was possible, indicate it might be possible, but offer no details at all on how to do it.

Comment: @sawdust The concept you're describing is called ICSP or in-circuit serial programming. Besides I2C, other popular interfaces are SPI and JTAG, and yes they are all serial. But whether or not it can be re-programmed in-circuit has nothing to do with the type of memory chip used, or at least not directly... but rather as a consequence of the system design. Technically, it's possible to design a system where a *parallel* EEPROM can be re-programmed, in-circuit! But the parallel nature of it would make it more complex. But still... it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS might be at real address F00000000 (F0000000:00000000). If so it takes up to 64 KB. If it is bigger than 64 KB the rest is in the real address space [3GB-(4GB-1)] including the 64 KB found at F00000000. So if you have access to real addressing you simply copy that to a file. But your OS might not give you real addressing, in stead you get memory mapping and possibly don't see the BIOS. With a debugger you can take a look at the address and see, if it looks right. The debugger also can write it to a file. The BIOS should contain a copyright message somewhere.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do such copy to a file and how can one discover about the real addressing of the in memory mapped BIOS?

Comment: It depends on the OS and the program you use for it. Also nowadays there is something named UEFI in stead of the BIOS, which I don't know anything about

Comment: The computer is an x86 that still has a regular BIOS (not UEFI) and the operating system may be any among MS-DOS, FreeDOS, Linux and FreeBSD, do you have any pointers on how to do it in this scenario?

Comment: For msdos/freedos most BIOS manufactures has a flash tool that can save a backup of the bios. If the pc is a Dell or HP you might be out of luck. Fx Ami: amiflash -r MyBiosBackup.bin.
Linux has a program, flashrom, which should be able to make a backup of the BIOS. There may be a version of it for FreeBSD

Comment: I was able to backup the contents with flashrom from a board whose BIOS has the desired version, but there seems to be some sort of manufacturer restriction about downgrading, so in the end I couldn't write to the other one. In any rate, these names didn't show up in my research, thanks for your helpful answer Mikkel!